# why cannot I use struct like this?

Tags: objective-c, struct

why cannot I use struct like this?

```
typedef struct { unsigned char FirstName; unsigned char LastName; unsigned int age; } User;
    User UserNick = {Nick, Watson, 24};

    NSLog(@"Your paint job is (R: %NSString, G: %NSString, B: %u)",
          UserNick.FirstName, UserNick.LastName, UserNick.age);
```

I mean I have used a struct like this for sure:

```
typedef struct {unsigned char red; unsigned char green; unsigned char blue; } Color;
    Color carColor = {255, 65,0};

NSLog(@"Your paint job is (R: %hhu, G: %hhu, B: %hhu)",
    carColor.red, carColor.green, carColor.blue);
```

Comment: BTW - why do you use `unsigned char` for the colors? You aren't storing characters but numbers. Using `uint8` would be a better choice.

Comment: @rmaddy Isn't `uint8` typedef'd to `unsigned char`?

Comment: @NobodyNada It may be but using `uint8` makes it clear you want an 8-bit number. Using `char` makes it look like you want a character.

Comment: @rmaddy You're right.  That's the reason `typedef` even exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use C strings you need the following code:

```
typedef struct { unsigned char *FirstName; unsigned char *LastName; unsigned int age; } User;
User UserNick = {"Nick", "Watson", 24};

NSLog(@"Your paint job is (R: %s, G: %s, B: %u)",
      UserNick.FirstName, UserNick.LastName, UserNick.age);
```

C strings are `char *`. C string literals need to be in quotes. `%s` is the format specifier for C strings.

One other suggestion - start field names (and variables names) with lowercase letters.

And since you are working with Objective-C, you would probably end up being better off if you make `User` a real class instead of a `struct`. Then you can use properties and proper memory management. The names could be `NSString` instead of C strings. This makes it easy to store the objects in collections and do other useful things that are hard with a plain old `struct`.

Comment: Thank You. Understood what you are saying.

Comment: Glad I could help. As a new user, please don't forget to accept answers that solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your definition, `FirstName` is an unsigned char which means it is a variable that can hold only one `char` as its value. However, `Nick` is a string, namely an array of chars.

One could do

```
typedef struct {
     unsigned char * FirstName;
     unsigned char * LastName;
     unsigned int age;
} User;
User Nick = {"Nick", "Watson", 24};
```